# Простой вопрос про запятую: "А больше, чем В"

Tags: синтаксис, пунктуация

Прочитала в записи задачи: "А больше, чем В на 69". И вдруг засомневалась: правильно ли расставлены запятые? То ли надо после "чем В" ставить еще запятую. То ли не надо перед "чем"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо выделить запятыми сравнительный оборот *чем В*.

*А больше, чем В, на 69.*

Здесь А сравнивается с В.

> Обороты, присоединяемые союзом «чем»,
> выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми,
> если в предложении называются или
> подразумеваются два сравниваемых
> понятия.
> [link text](http://gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/58_68)

Comment: Да, я тоже так подумала. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

DocentI, по всем правилам здесь требуется обособление только оборота "чем Б", "на 69" (или там "на 10 см") к нему не относится. Так что вариант с одной запятой исключен изначально. А вот почему "очень хочется" - в математическом особенно тексте - оставить без обособления, я не могу понять, но, ручаюсь, это не только у нас двоих.

Я отвергаю аналогию с контрукцией "А больше Б" потому, что это синтаксически другая конструкция. Сравните: "Гипотенуза бельше, чем катет" и "Гипотенуза больше катета". Другой падеж, даже любимая Виктором прямая замена не проходит.
Выскажу в порядке бреда крамольную мысль. "Больше чем" выступат здесь в роли сказуемого (или же вопринимается таковым, не хочу заниматься терминологическими спорами), а в подобных случаях обычно запятая "внутри" сказуемого не ставится. Обратите внимение, "Б" или "катет" тут стоит в именительном падеже. Ситуация сразу меняется, как только меняется падеж. *У квадрата площадь больше, чем у вписанного в него круга, на столько-то процентов.* Ни о каких вольностях в пунктуации даже не помышляешь.

Повторяю, всё это не рекомендация, а лишь попытка объяснить затрудние. Рекомендация: обособлять "чем Б" во всех подобных случаях. Правило и источники тут уже обсосали со всех сторон.

Answer (score 1):

Марина, но ведь во всех примерах того правила, на которое Вы ссылаетесь, нет конструкции, похожей на ту, которая находится в обсуждаемом вопросе. Я посмотрел и РОзенталя, и Лопатина, но везде конструкции другие: там оборот с "чем" находится в конце предложения, а в поставленном вопросе - в середине предложения. Мне кажется, что запятая здесь не нужна, так как, выбросив "чем", мы получаем нормальную фразу: "А больше В на 69"

Comment: Виктор, у Розенталя в "Справочнике по русскому языку. Пунктуация" гораздо больше примеров, чем в его же "Справочнике по правописанию и стилистике" (судя по всему, вы пользуетесь им). Я уже говорила об этом, а наш общий друг Бегемот давал ссылку с текстом без рекламы http://lib.rus.ec/b/118184/read.
Примеры с оборотом не в конце предложения из этого справочника:
Больше, чем от физической боли, он страдал от мысли, что он теперь инвалид (газ.); Больше, чем что-либо другое, больному нужен покой.

Comment: Спасибо, Марина, это меняет дело

Comment: Пожалуйста, пользуйтесь )

Answer (score 1):

Отсутствие запятой после сравнительного оборота, как и ваше сомнение - то ли одну запятую убрать, то ли вторую поставить - вызвано интерференцией с более употребительной в этом стиле языка конструкцией "А больше В на...", где никаких запятых не нужно. То есть либо с "чем" и двумя запятыми, либо без "чем" и без запятых :)

Comment: Бывает, что дано предложение и из него нельзя ни одного слова "выбросить", а можно только правильно расставить знаки.

Виктор, над вашим замечанием я пока еще думаю )

Comment: Вопрос возник при просмотре "Математики". Конечно, там нет особых требований к грамотности. Мне понравилась идея вообще убрать "чем". Если буду использовать эту задачу, так и сделаю.